# Occluded Objects

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

Does anybody have an idea about how to separate or detect   overlapped objects?
I am currently working on a project aiming at the detection crops in the late stage of growth. I did the first step, which is the segmentation (segment the plants from the background), but I got stack with detection stage because of  overlapping between  two crops or more (cauliflower).
By the way, I am working on Opencv and visual C++. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Often, object detection algorithms try to be resilient to some degree of occlusion. This is easier than trying to determine which part of the object is occluded.

Comment: Thanks Victor May for your reply.To get a clear picture this is my sample,http://labs.tineye.com/color/64615cc7415c33fce148e7eb40402698ffc4e294